# Reveal app window from command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, applescript

I'm trying to bring back up a minimized `mpv` window using a keyboard shortcut.

I use `skhd` to map keyboard shortcuts to various `open` commands, so I can quickly launch frequently used apps. This has the nice side-effect of also revealing hidden windows (e.g. if I minimize Safari, I can hit my Safari keyboard shortcut and have it pop back up for me); however this doesn't seem to work for apps designed to be launched from the command-line (e.g. `mpv`).

Is there a better/easier way of doing this? `open -a mpv` doesn't have the desired effect.

UPDATE: Building off what Allan posted below (thanks!), I was able to make the process window become active with the following:
`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "mpv"' -e 'perform action "AXRaise" of item 1 of windows' -e 'set frontmost to true' -e 'end tell'`

Comment: You'll need to do this via Applescript.  Here's a simple (meaning no error checking) on-liner that will open Terminal if it's minimized:  `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 of application process "Terminal"'`. It works in Ventura launched from iTerm2.

Comment: @Allan I had a feeling. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @Allan one more thing - I can't seem to find this in the AppleScript documentation - the prior-active app stays active even after the window I want is brought back up. I'm running this on the command line so can't split lines up properly (and I've tried \n) - is there a way to also activate the app/window that comes up?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re getting at, can you clarify?  You want the UI to switch from terminal where you’re currently active to the window that was just raised from the dock¿

Comment: @Allan yes, correct.